# getting 403 disallowed user agent in Auth0 Lock for Android

Tags: android, google-oauth, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

integrated Auth0 login in my android application.
for this integration i am following this one
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-android

its work fine previously, but now i am facing 403 disallowed user while click on google.

while i am searching in google i found this:
Google since april 20 decided to block access from embedded webviews for security purposes thats why Auth0 login with google fails.

iOS guys fixed the same issue using:

but didn't find this in android

how to resolve this.
any have idea on this.

my piece of code:

```
compile 'com.auth0.android:lock:2.+'

Auth0 auth0 = new Auth0(getString(R.string.auth0_client_id), getString(R.string.auth0_domain));
            mLock = Lock.newBuilder(auth0, mCallback)
                    //Add parameters to the builder
                    .closable(true)
                    .build(this);
            startActivity(mLock.newIntent(this));

private LockCallback callback = new AuthenticationCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthentication(Credentials credentials) {
          //Authenticated
       }

       @Override
       public void onCanceled() {
          //User pressed back
       }

       @Override
       public void onError(LockException error) {
          //Exception occurred
       }
   };
```

manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.auth0.android.lock.LockActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/MyLock.Theme">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

      <data
        android:host="quikdeal1.auth0.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/android/{YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}/callback"
        android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Since Google blocks requests from a `WebView`, we need to set a user agent ourselves before making the request.

Using a hard-coded fake user agent as given in other answers has a disadvantage. Gmail sends email to the user telling that their account has been logged in from a particular device (which is not their device, and may lead to suspicion).

Using the System's default user agent worked for me.

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(System.getProperty("http.agent"));
```

Comment: What does http.agent means? Should it be https.agent? Can you please elaborate on this

Comment: @ManojPerumarath "The HTTP headers User-Agent is a request header that allows a characteristic string that allows network protocol peers to identify the Operating System and Browser of the web-server [src: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-user-agent/ ]". To my knowledge, HTTPS also uses HTTP headers. So, using `http.agent` should be fine as it is just a key to retrieve the required system property.

Comment: This works! Using this, Gmail also sends the security alert email though, but it looks way better than hardcoding a user agent

Comment: This method is worked. But getting very strange super simplified version of login page. I think this because server side detection can not detect web engine version and provides very simplified layout. I added alternative way in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72642783/6124347

Answer (score 13):

As you said, google decided to block access from embedded `WebView`s.
The same has happened to me and i just put the user-agent by myself.
It looks like this:

```
public static final String USER_AGENT_FAKE = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT_FAKE);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks man. but my peace of code is 
Auth0 auth0 = new Auth0(getString(R.string.auth0_client_id), getString(R.string.auth0_domain)); 
mLock = Lock.newBuilder(auth0, mCallback) //Add parameters to the builder .closable(true) .build(this); 
startActivity(mLock.newIntent(this)); 
don't have webview variable in my source code

Comment: sorry i don't know this library... try to find a way to set the user agent manually.

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me:

```
private WebView mWebView;

public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct but when using this USER_AGENT, Youtube video not playing.

Comment: You need to set different user agent for api 21 and above. Check webview on android section https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Answer (score 3):

Another more attractive way is to remove the WebView `wv` flag from the real WebView's UserAgent.

Аccording [to Chrome for Android User-Agent Strings documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/user-agent/#webview_user_agent) :

**WebView UA in Lollipop and Above**

In the newer versions of WebView, you can differentiate the WebView by looking for the `wv` field as highlighted below.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

So you should set User Agent like this:

```
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
            webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace("; wv)", ")")
    );
```

As a result, all important information about device OS, the version of the web engine used in WebView is left for statistics and cross-platform layout, if the site uses it. The page opened in WebView will be displayed as correctly as possible.

Also please note that this approach is relevant if your `minSdk 21`. For older version there is another User-Agent string template (described in above link).

Answer (score 1):

Google to block web views from using its OAuth.
[Reference link](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/23/google_to_block_web_views_from_using_its_oauth/)

You need to do OAuth through native code. or use some alternative of Webview

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @OShiffer you need to add a fake user agent but now it's outdated you have to use new one instead. Use this one

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-J105H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Mobile Safari/537.36";
```

Comment: It's worked. But there is no user's account on open dialog. User have input the email and password.

Comment: Also I have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I ran into this same issue and struggled with it for a while before realizing that a lot of Android simulators do not come with a valid default browser installed. Simply using a device that had Chrome installed fixed this bug for me. See this really well-detailed answer here: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/716

Comment: Please do not provide links in an answer, if you want to use links please mark the question as duplicate and use a comment to provide the link.