# Google and Facebook Login Error in webview Kotlin App

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, google-chrome, webview

am using Webview to turn my responsive website into a native app. All the things are working fine the thing is whenever I try to login with Facebook or Google they give an error some attachment put down anyone can help me out with this problem. Here's the [error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeKiX.jpg) by google.

Advance thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting 403 disallowed user agent in Auth0 Lock for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972730/getting-403-disallowed-user-agent-in-auth0-lock-for-android)

Comment: share you webview implementation code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.