# 403 disallowed user agent in Auth0 Lock for Android

Tags: android, webview, uiwebview, android-webview

This question has been asked and answered before but due to the limitation of not being able to comment when less than 50 reputation points, I have to make this a question instead.

I wanted someone to help me how to get back to my own website after using user-agent as specified in this answer [setting user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72642783/20692036).

I get this

[image: this]

after clicking Login with Google

[image: Login with Google]

instead of getting redirected after the authentication to the preference filling I instead get this white screen.

[image: this]

This also does not seem to be an emulator-only issue as well as I have found in some Stackoverflow threads as it is still the same when I run it on my Android 10 device Samsung S9 when installing the app.

Most probably, the issue is that I have set no webpage to load after user agent but since I am new to this, I don't have a lot of idea on how to do that. Please, point me in the right direction.

[This](https://selectpreference.web.app/) is the website built by my friend if you go in and fill preference you should be able to log in and that's what I wanted to implement in a WebView for my Android Application.
Also here is how I have coded my app if it helps any better to debug the issue...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
                webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace("; wv)", ")")
        );
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://selectpreference.web.app/");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

As for the XML it's only a WebView.
Thanks for reading this post.